# How to achieve a "mini" select style using Bootstrap (or straight CSS)?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

I'm using Bootstrap's `btn-mini` class for "mini" buttons and am looking for something analogous to create a "mini" select element, where the select button (i.e. the part you click to show the list of options, not the list of options itself) is the same size and style as a mini button.

When I apply the `btn-mini` class to a select element, the font style of the select button is the same size as a mini button, but the size of the select button itself is unchanged from the default size.

Is there a different Bootstrap class I should use? Or another way to do it?

P.S. I'm working on OS X Chrome, but naturally hope there is a cross-browser compatible solution.

Comment: if you want to shrink a select menu, you need only adjust the `font-size`, and perhaps add a bit of padding to make it more legible

Comment: @jackwanders -- that doesn't seem to be enough. The Bootstrap CSS class `btn-mini` includes a `font-size` adjustment. When applied to a select, the class makes the font size smaller, but without shrinking the box size down.

Comment: that's because `.btn-mini` also includes rules for line-height and padding. `.btn-mini` wasn't designed to be used with `select` elements. You're better off making your own class. See this demo to see what I'm talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/jackwanders/NQPBW/

Comment: Copy the css and HTML into your question, and I'm sure someone will be along briefly with the answer.

Comment: @jackwanders -- hmmm, the select box shrinks to the size of the font in the fiddle, but not with Bootstrap. Seems like Bootstrap is fixing the height of selects regardless of the font size...

Comment: Ok, got it. Bootstrap's CSS indeed sets both the `height` and `line-height` of selects in various places. So explicitly setting both to what I want works.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

### HTML

```
<select class="btn btn-mini">
    <!-- options -->
</select>
<span class="caret"></span>
```

### CSS

```
select.btn-mini {
    height: auto;
    line-height: 14px;
}

/* this is optional (see below) */
select.btn {
    -webkit-appearance: button;
       -moz-appearance: button;
            appearance: button;
    padding-right: 16px;
}

select.btn-mini + .caret {
    margin-left: -20px;
    margin-top: 9px;
}
```

The last 2 rules are optional, it will make `<select>` look like `<button>`, I've also added a caret to it. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x3Xzs/253/).

Comment: That's nice! Changing the appearance to a button, together with the application of the new `select.btn-mini` rule is what makes it look consistent. Now, for the caret, any tips on how to do that?

Comment: This is awesome and should be included as part of the default Bootstrap. Thank you!

Comment: Just checked this on Firefox (20-something) on a MacBook Pro. What I see in the JS Fiddle is a select with two drop-down triangles (caret). Nice concept, though, just seems a bit odd. Must be my machine.

Comment: @Ace Looks like `-moz-appearance` has no effect on Firefox 20 (and probably earlier). Non-standard properties are evil after all. I will think how to modify this answer.

Answer (score 62):

Just in case any Bootstrap 3 users come across this old question, here's the BS3 way:

```
<select class="form-control input-lg"></select>
<select class="form-control"></select>
<select class="form-control input-sm"></select>

<input class="form-control input-lg">
<input class="form-control">
<input class="form-control input-sm">
```

There is no input-xs, though, so you'd have to make that yourself if you wanted smaller.

```
.input-xs, select.input-xs {
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Doesnt work if select size > 1 for this case what it should do is reduce the text size and padding.

Answer (score 12):

For **Bootstrap 4**, to set **height** we can use `form-control-sm` class with `form-control`.

```
<select class="form-control form-control-lg">
  <option>Large select</option>
</select>
<select class="form-control">
  <option>Default select</option>
</select>
<select class="form-control form-control-sm">
  <option>Small select</option>
</select>
```

[image]

And to set **width** of these we have to use grid column classes like `.col-sm-*`, `.col-md-*`, `.col-lg-*`, etc.

So put the select code in:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    ... select tag code ...
  </div>
</div>
```

and it will look like this:

[image]

You can call the last one a **"mini"** select element.

Comment: ok, tested it: <select class="custom-select custom-select-sm">   does work as well. Awesome!

Answer (score 2):

This is not a final answer, but I wanted to share what I've gotten so far for anyone else curious about doing this.

As suggested by jackwanders, I've gone ahead and created a custom CSS class:

```
.select-mini {
  font-size: 11px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

This `font-size` and `height` rules more or less get the select box to be the same size as a mini button, but the text isn't quite aligned in the same way (it's slightly shifted up). Note you need to use `height` not `line-height` to override a `height` rule for select elements that Bootstrap sets elsewhere. (The `width` rule is just to change the widget and can be whatever you want.)

My CSS-fu isn't good enough to quickly make the mini select look fully consistent with the mini buttons, and from what I can see select's behave oddly when it comes to CSS anyhow, but hopefully this will be helpful as a start to others. Meanwhile, still open to better answers!

Answer (score 0):

Based on `btn-xs` class I've prepared this:

```
.input-xs{
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 1px 5px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```

Note that width is not limited!

Please check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yhngqvqy/) to see it in action.

Answer (score 0):

Pavlo answer is better. But when mouse cursor is over caret click doenst` work. Just one thing must be added into caret class to fix it:

```css
select.btn-mini + .caret {
    margin-left: -14px;
    margin-top: 19px;
 pointer-events: none;
}
```